# Flask, Jinja2 partially rendering template

Tags: templates, flask, jinja2, render

So I have some amount of data pulled from a database in a table format and this table have some user input forms embedded in it. 
In terms of functionality, everything works fine but I would like to know a way where I can only render the table part of a template rather than rendering whole template every time a user makes some posts requests. I've searched quite a bit but I could not find a good solution just using Flask and JINJA2.
Is using Ajax and Javascript the only solutions that I have?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you could pass a variable to the page that indicates whether you want to show all the info or only part of it.

Flask

```
showAll = False
render_template('page', showAll = showAll)
```

Then you could use that variable to decide whether or not to show a certain part of the HTML code.

```
{% if showAll != False %}
  <p> Since I set showAll to False I will not be shown on web page<p>
{% endif %}
```

That is one way that you can accomplish this; however, it is a little complicated. I would suggest AJAX and Javascript.

Comment: @Myers, will this work on post requests too? so everytime user presses a submit or update button where it requires a post request from server, would it also render partial template?

Comment: Yes, but it will cause a redirect each time. Therefor if you want to avoid that you should probably go with the ajax route. If you need an example of ajax I can try to come up with a quick one.